# Convert a dataframe containing a list of dictionaries to a several rows in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following problem, I have a dataframe that contains two columns with a list of dictionaries. The scheme that I have created for the data structure that I have is the following:

```
        tick_by_tick_schema = StructType([
            StructField('localSymbol', StringType()),
            StructField('tickByTicks', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price', StringType()),
                StructField('size', StringType()),
                StructField('specialConditions', StringType()),
            ]))),
            StructField('domBids', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price_bid', StringType()),
                StructField('size_bid', StringType()),
                StructField('marketMaker_bid', StringType()),
            ])))
        ])
```

My dataframe is this:

```
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|localSymbol|tickByTicks     |domBids                                                                                 |
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now what I would like to get is something like this:

```
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+-----+
|localSymbol|tickByTicks     |domBids                                                                                 |price_bid|marketMaker_bid|price|
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+-----+
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|32.8     |CHX            |32.99|
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|32.8     |MEMX           |32.99|
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|32.8     |NYSENAT        |32.99|
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|32.79    |NSDQ           |32.99|
|ALKT       |[{32.99, 100, }]|[{32.8, 1, CHX}, {32.8, 1, MEMX}, {32.8, 1, NYSENAT}, {32.79, 1, NSDQ}, {32.69, 1, BYX}]|32.69    |BYX            |32.99|
+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+-----+
```

I tried this, but obviously it doesn't work xD

```
df = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed.select(f.col('localSymbol'),f.col('tickByTicks'),f.col('domBids'))\
    .withColumn('price_bid', f.explode(f.col('tickByTicks.price'))) \
    .withColumn('marketMaker_bid', f.explode(f.col('domBids.marketMaker_bid'))) \
    .withColumn('price_bid', f.explode(f.col('domBids.price_bid')))
```

Comment: I think you need to  use `explode` to split `domBids` into separate rows, then split them into separate columns.

Comment: I think not because you are doing a cartesian multiplication, or at least as I am doing it as you say it does not work for me. Could you write me the code?

Comment: I don't know what's the right way to do it in PySpark - it just looks to me like something that in Pandas could be solved by using `explode` to get single values instead of list cells. I figured maybe that would get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```py
# It explodes and select all struct columns
df = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed \
    .withColumn('tick', f.explode(f.col('tickByTicks'))) \
    .withColumn('dom', f.explode(f.col('domBids'))) \
    .select('localSymbol', 'tick.*', 'dom.*')

# OR

# Selecting only desired columns
df = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed \
    .withColumn('tick', f.explode(f.col('tickByTicks'))) \
    .withColumn('dom', f.explode(f.col('domBids'))) \
    .select('localSymbol', 
            f.col('tick.price').alias('tick_price'), 
            f.col('dom.marketMaker_bid').alias('marketMaker_bid'),
            f.col('dom.price_bid').alias('price_bid'))
```

Comment: sorry I just got home, it works, I had a thing wrong set in spark. thank you!!!! :)